# Multinomial gam diagnostic help

Tags: predictive-models, generalized-additive-model, multinomial-distribution, mgcv, diagnostic

I have created a Generalized additive model of a multinomial distribution using the `mgcv` package, I have used check.gam to do some diagnostic tests but they look pretty dodgy and I'm not sure completely what they mean. Could anyone help me interpret them.

First the model:

```r
model1 <- gam(list(substrate.numeric ~ s(depth) + s(slope) + 
              s(aspect), ~ s(depth) + s(slope) + s(aspect), 
              ~ s(depth) + s(slope) + s(aspect), ~ s(depth) + 
              s(slope) + s(aspect), ~s(depth) + s(slope) + s(aspect)), 
              family = multinom(K = 5), data = model.data)
```

The 'model.data' dataframe is a dataframe with 126 observations, the response variable 'substrate.numeric' is numeric (0-5) representing the 6 habitat classes.

the three explanatory variables are depth, slope and aspect and they are all continuous.

here is the gam.check output:

```r
Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 17 iterations.
Gradient range [-2.181209e-05,4.478479e-06]
(score 112.4147 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [4.118078e-07,0.7622996].
Model rank =  140 / 140 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

              k'  edf k-index p-value
s(depth)    9.00 1.00    1.15    0.96
s(slope)    9.00 1.64    1.10    0.82
s(aspect)   9.00 1.00    1.05    0.70
s.1(depth)  9.00 2.07    1.15    0.94
s.1(slope)  9.00 1.00    1.10    0.81
s.1(aspect) 9.00 1.00    1.05    0.72
s.2(depth)  9.00 5.41    1.15    0.95
s.2(slope)  9.00 1.00    1.10    0.81
s.2(aspect) 9.00 1.00    1.05    0.73
s.3(depth)  9.00 1.57    1.15    0.95
s.3(slope)  9.00 1.57    1.10    0.84
s.3(aspect) 9.00 3.51    1.05    0.68
s.4(depth)  9.00 3.09    1.15    0.94
s.4(slope)  9.00 2.77    1.10    0.80
s.4(aspect) 9.00 2.88    1.05    0.64
```

And here are the figures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My vague attempt at understanding is that the response variable is the presence or absence for 6 substrate classes so I'm wondering if presence appears as positive and absence appears as negative which is cause the two distinct groups of residuals in the models. However, this is all quite unfamiliar to me so please help.

From the summary of the model I knew that it was not particularly well fitting and I'm certain the sample size is far too small but I'm using existing data so I can't fix that.
However I want to be able to recommend areas for future work being to collect much more data and then use this model again. However if these diagnostics mean this is going to be impossible I'd also like to know. Any help much appreciated.